# Installed apache spark in multi node mode. Now if I what to install yarn as my cluster manager how to proced as I already have installed Spark

Tags: apache-spark

New to spark. Installed apache spark in multi node mode. Now if I what to install yarn as my cluster manager how to proced as I already have installed spark. Also now by default how are my task assigned to different workers?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Yarn doesn't depend upon Spark installation. Yarn is only a cluster manager. While submitting the jar you should specify the --master as yarn.

Refer the below doc.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html